# Get a text in the span, using protractor

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine, protractor

I need to check, using expect and Jasmine, if the text of the span in the button is "Vigente". How can I do it?

```
<button _ngcontent-hke-28="" class="btn btn-success disabled" tabindex="-1">
<span _ngcontent-hke-28="" class="glyphicon glyphicon-check">
</span> Vigente</button>
```

Can I use xpath like this:

> /html/body/application/auth-container/layout/div/main-content/div/norma-cadastro/div/form/div[8]/div/button/text(Vigente)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, the XPath expression you are asking about is not correct - the `Vigente` part inside the parenthesis is not needed. Also, try not use absolute XPath expressions as the more levels in the path you have, the higher chances it'll break. And, [XPaths are not recommended by the Protractor team](http://www.protractortest.org/#/style-guide#never-use-xpath).

Instead, I would locate the element [*by partial button text*](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorBy.prototype.partialButtonText) and check the presence of this element:

```
expect(element(by.partialButtonText("Vigente")).isPresent()).toBe(true);
```

Or, you can locate the element by, say, a CSS selector and get the text:

```
expect($("button.btn-success").getText()).toContain(Vigente);
```

The `button.btn-success` CSS selector is though quite broad, see if you can improve it.

Comment: And if I have a button with text "Vigência invalida".
I'm trying using 
`expect(element(by.partialButtonText(" Vigência invalida")).isPresent()).toBe(true);`
but it's not working

Comment: @paulotarcio okay, are you sure the leading space is needed? Thanks.

Comment: I tried without the leading space and with the leaging space, both didn't work

Comment: @paulotarcio this button might be represented differently on the page. Could you show its html representation? Thanks.

Comment: @alexcxe I don't know how to indent it. but there is it: I have two input date, and if I put a final date > inicial date, the button must change to "vigência invalida" <button _ngcontent-lgk-11="" class="btn btn-warning disabled" tabindex="-1"><span _ngcontent-lgk-11="" class="glyphicon glyphicon-check"></span> Vigência invalida</button>

Answer (score 0):

Can't say if it is correct or not.. But you can check it yourself in Chrome Dev tools. Just do inspect element on the element. And then right click on the element in HTML and click Copy. I would recommend using ID's or angular model if you can. XPaths change with changing HTML (unless you use ID's in XPath anyway) and then maintaining the tests becomes a task.

See the image.

[image]

Comment: I can't use model or id because the develepors doesn't have the habit to use it. That's why I'm using xpath